# Find out the volume of data sent through my ASP site

Tags: asp-classic

I'd like to be able to see the web pages I'm serving on my Classic ASP site and how much data is sent out in preparation to start using GZip compression on the server. Running Windows Server 2003.

Is there a tool/utility/script to be able to watch or log traffic and tell the bytes going ou?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diodeus is right in saying that you need a web log analyzer.

My current webhost uses SmarterStats which is has a large range of customisable reports available and is very good for looking at things like traffic volume etc as it'll visualise it all in the browser for you.

If you are running your own server then you can get a free edition which can be used with just one website - http://www.smartertools.com/smarterstats/free-web-analytics-seo-software.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need a log analyzer for IIS. [Webtrends](http://www.webtrends.com) used to be quite popular. I used it a dog's life ago. Most use Google Analytics these days, but it's a different beast and tracks traffic, not data transfer volume. You really need to look at the server logs for that.